# Is my Object Casting Model acceptable?

Tags: splistitem, splist, splistitemcollection, patterns-and-practices, design-patterns

I'm creating a SharePoint application, and am trying some new things to create what amounts to an API for Data Access to maintain consistency and conventions.

I haven't seen this before, and that makes me think it might be bad :)

I've overloaded the constructor for `class Post` to only take an `SPListItem` as a parameter. I then have an embedded Generic List of `Post` that takes an SPListItemCollection in the method signature.

I loop through the items in a more efficient `for` statement, and this means if I ever need to add or modify how the `Post` object is cast, I can do it in the Class definition for a single source.

```
class Post
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public Post(SPListItem item)
    {
        ID = item.ID;
        Title = (string)item["Title"];
    }
    public static List<Post> Posts(SPListItemCollection _items)
    {
        var returnlist = new List<Post>();
        for (int i = 0; i < _items.Count; i++) {returnlist.Add(new Post(_items[i]));}
        return returnlist;
    }
}
```

This enables me to do the following:

```
    static public List<Post> GetPostsByCommunity(string communityName) 
    {
        var targetList = CoreLists.SystemAccount.Posts(); //CAML emitted for brevity
        return Post.Posts(targetList.GetItems(query)); //Call the constructor
    }
```

Is this a bad idea?